# Trying to use Terraform with GCP Workload Identity Federation returns `ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT`

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, workload-identity

I try to run Terraform to create a GKE cluster in GitLab CI/CD using the `CI_JOB_JWT_V2` with Workload Identity Federation. Terraform returns `ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT`, and I have no idea why (Google did not help).

This is a copy of the GitLab CI output that shows that I managed to successfully authenticate with the desired service account.

```
$ gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config ${GCP_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER} --service-account="${GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}" --output-file=.gcp_temp_cred.json --executable-command='cat ${CI_JOB_JWT_V2}'
Created credential configuration file [.gcp_temp_cred.json].
$ gcloud auth login --cred-file=`pwd`/.gcp_temp_cred.json --project=$GCP_PROJECT_ID
Authenticated with external account credentials for: [tanzu-test@vnagy-ec626bda.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
Your current project is [vnagy-ec626bda].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
$ gcloud auth list
                            Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
        ephemeral-runner@gitlab-ci-plan-free-3-35411a.iam.gserviceaccount.com
*       tanzu-test@vnagy-ec626bda.iam.gserviceaccount.com
To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

Still, a few lines later, the same CI job returns

```
Terraform has been successfully initialized!
google_container_cluster.primary: Creating...
╷
│ Error: googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "googleapis.com",
│     "metadata": {
│       "method": "google.container.v1.ClusterManager.CreateCluster",
│       "service": "container.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
│   }
│ ]
│ 
│ More details:
│ Reason: insufficientPermissions, Message: Insufficient Permission
│ 
│ 
│   with google_container_cluster.primary,
│   on gke.tf line 1, in resource "google_container_cluster" "primary":
│    1: resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
│ 
╵
```

I checked the logs of the Workload Identity Pool and the Service account. Both logs are empty. This leaves me puzzled as authentication seems to work, so I'd expect some logs to show up.

Within GCP, the service account in question has the following permissions:

[image: IAM for the service account]

These permissions seem to be okay. I quickly created a cluster from the GCP web console using `gcloud --impersonate-service-account=...`. It worked.

Comment: **scopes** mean permissions. You need Workload Identity Pool Admin (roles/iam.workloadIdentityPoolAdmin) and 
Service Account Admin (roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin) Details: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm the project owner. I could configure the Workload Idenditity Pool and the Service Account.

Comment: You still have a permission problem. Do not assume the permissions that `Owner` has, which are not all permissions. Some must be added. Double-check which identity is having the problem. Your post only has the error message which is not all that helpful.

Comment: @JohnHanley from the docs you linked: "Alternatively, the IAM Owner (roles/owner) basic role also includes permissions to configure identity federation. You should not grant basic roles in a production environment, but you can grant them in a development or test environment." I agree that I have a permissions problem, but I think it's not with my regular user, but the service account - IDP connection. "Your post only has the error message which is not all that helpful." - Let me know what extra info you might need. I'm happy to share more.